# Is a true RNN auto encoder possible with Keras/TF

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, python, keras, recurrent-neural-networks

I want to get some encodings for temporal data (with a highly varying number of timesteps).

The dataset is of the format: `array<TemporalSample = list, SAMPLE_COUNT>` (where `array` is fixed size and `list` is variable).

The `TemporalSample`s are simply `list`s of size `TemporalSample::timesteps`

---

Currently, I use a standard RNN network of the form:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(256, dropout=0.1, input_shape=[None, 1], return_sequences=False))
model.add(layers.Dense(len(output_names), activation="softmax"))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

The problem is my inputs have variable lengths, if I want an auto-encoder, my output needs to be variable-length (just like my input), and I need an inverse RNN layer (something like `layers.InverseGRU(output_shape=[None, 1])`) but from my reading this seems like not something that has been considered/done before.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: As I wrote for the other post, it's not clear to me whether this is a programming issue. Can you clarify this?

Comment: @nbro I'm asking if I can build a RNN auto encoder - using python examples for context

Comment: For some reason, it wasn't clear to me after the first reading that you just want to build an AE with recurrent layers.

Comment: @nbro the main problem is i have variable length timesteps

Comment: Ok, I will leave this post open, although you also asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67028618/3924118), so that maybe someone tries to give you an answer ;)

Comment: @nbro I asked here as this is a more AI focused community (the answer on SO is wrong)

Comment: What about this: https://machinelearningmastery.com/lstm-autoencoders/?

Comment: @nbro doesn't account for variable timesteps

Comment: Ok. I didn't read that article, but it seemed to go in the direction of what you were asking (although, to be honest, I didn't carefully read your post).

Comment: @nbro I actually have a working encoder now (at the time of writing this post I didn't); however, I'm still interested to see if anyone has any differing techniques