# Are there any inverse RNN layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-networks

Given the model:

```
Sequence([
GRU(200, input_shape=(None,100), return_sequences=False)
])
```

Which maps the space `(None, 100) -> (200,)`

Is there an `InverseGRU` such that it maps the space `(200,) -> (None, 100)`

or, at least, is it possible to simulate this behaviour?

Comment: This seems to be somehow a duplicate of this: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/27246/2444.

Comment: @nbro its part of the same problem, but tackling a different aspect. That question is more general, this question is about whether this specific type of layer exists - and where its even possible to implement